# How to modify WearableActionDrawer on runtime?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created an ActionDrawer for my Wear OS App and want to change the icon and text on runtime. This code is working and my app continues to run without errors, but I am not able to slide up the ActionDrawer anymore. Also, when the ActionDrawerMenu is already opened and I press the button there, it disappears and my UI of the app seems frozen.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Top navigation drawer
    WearableNavigationDrawerView wearableNavigationDrawer = (WearableNavigationDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.top_navigation_drawer);
    wearableNavigationDrawer.setAdapter(new NavigationDrawerAdapter());
    wearableNavigationDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();

    //Bottom action drawer
    WearableActionDrawerView wearableActionDrawer = (WearableActionDrawerView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_action_drawer);
    wearableActionDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();
    wearableActionDrawer.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
    final int itemId = menuItem.getItemId();

    switch(itemId) {
        case R.id.menuItem_pause:
            if(intent == null) {
                menuItem.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
                menuItem.setTitle(R.string.actionDrawerMenuPause);
            } else {
                menuItem.setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
                menuItem.setTitle(R.string.actionDrawerMenuStart);
            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have tried some solutions with invalidateOptionsMenu(), onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onCreateOptionsMenu() but nothing worked for me. I think this just works with standard Android mobile apps but not with Wear OS. So how can I change the text and icon of my WearableActionDrawer-MenuItems when pressing a MenuItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by accident. It's just this one line of code that programmatically implements the menu.

```
//Bottom action drawer
WearableActionDrawerView wearableActionDrawer = findViewById(R.id.bottom_action_drawer);
wearableActionDrawer.getController().peekDrawer();
wearableActionDrawer.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_drawer_menu, wearableActionDrawer.getMenu());
```